# In Ruby on Rails, how can I pass params[:id]?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, parameters

In my home page I have:

```
# /views/static_pages/home.html.erb
<%= render @posts %>
```

and:

```
# /views/posts/_post.html.erb
<%= link_to 'haha', ?????? %>
```

Through the controller:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @posts = Post.all.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
end
```

and:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def show
   @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

I want to get the page:

```
# /views/posts/show.html.erb
<%= @post.name %>
```

by clicking the "haha" link to pass `params[:id]` to get the page /posts/:id.

But I dont know what to do to replace the ??????.

Also, the routes are:

```
Tradeincu::Application.routes.draw do  
  resources :users, :only => [:show]
  match '/users/:id', to: 'users#show', via: 'get'
  resources :posts
end
```

Comment: Have you tried `<%= link_to 'haha', post %>`?

Comment: Can't believe it is so simple!! got it! thanks

Comment: See [Layouts and Rendering in Rails - Rendering Collections](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections): *"... within the `_product` partial, you can refer to `product` to get the instance that is being rendered."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways of doing this, you could use:

```
<%= link_to 'haha', post_path(post) %>
```

Or:

```
<%= link_to "haha", controller: "posts", action: "show", id: post %>
```

You can see the documetation along with some examples [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to).

Comment: not working, its said 'No route matches {:id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]'

Comment: @FengDing Wich action is the one that renders '_post' view?

Comment: i think its <%= render @posts %>. btw. Stefan's solution solved this. thank you all the same. and the examples.

Comment: @FengDing I didn't realize you were rendering `@posts`. In that case you should use `post` instead of `@post`. I'll update my answer for future viewers